# How to place a custom PHP file in the cPanel root folder

Tags: php, linux, cpanel, root, whm

I have a custom PHP file that needs placing in a the cpanel/root folder. Any root folder, be it newly created or  /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/.

This is the error I got, when I placed it in one of my accounts:

```
PHP Warning: opendir(/var/named/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/****/public_html/cpanel-slave-zones-add.php on line 46
```

This the response I got from the script developers:

> The "ZONES_DIR" is pre-defined in the PHP file as "/var/named/". However, since you are received such error, we recommend you to place the script into the root directory ("/").

Do you  know where should I put this script, so it can function properly? Do you know, ways to go about?

Comment: Hi Wundder Labs. Welcome to SO. please do not post extra information as comments, rather, edit your original question to give as much detail information as you deem relevant to ansswer your issue.

Comment: You write "placing" how are you placing it ? through an ftp client? via a web interface belonging to cpanel? through some other interface? When do you experience the error?`while accessing the file? while accessing the site? while uploading it? please include as much information as you would imagine you would need to answer another person's question.